# Without numpy, I cannot perform an undetermined number of polynomial multiplications in Python

Tags: python, polynomial-math

I want to calculate the coefficients of a polynomial that vanishes on points from a list, for example, the following code has three roots, 1, 2, and 3. It is not known how many roots these components have, so I need to obtain their final coefficients.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

mult = defaultdict(int)
a=[1, 2, 3]
def loop_rec(a, n, item1, item2):
    if n > 0:
        for i1, c1 in zip([1,0], [1, -a[n]]):
            for i2, c2 in zip(item1, item2):
                mult[i1 + i2] += c1 * c2
                mult_sorted = tuple(sorted(mult.items(), reverse=True))
                item1 = [item[0] for item in mult_sorted]
                item2 = [item[1] for item in mult_sorted]
                a=a[:n]
        loop_rec(a, n - 1, item1, item2)
    else:
       return (item1,item2)
(a,b)=loop_rec(a,len(a)-1,[0],[1])
```

```
[out]: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: How do you achieve it using numpy? Have you tried looking through the source code?

Comment: @definaly Thanks for your response, but the problem was in all cases I had to use a sub-function from NumPy and it was problematic when I am working on a finite field. BTW thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
mult = defaultdict(int)
a=[1, 2, 3]
def loop_rec(a, n, item1, item2):
    if n >= 0:
        mult = defaultdict(int)
        for i1, c1 in zip([1,0], [1, a[n]]):
            for i2, c2 in zip(item1, item2):
                mult[i1 + i2] += c1 * c2
        mult_sorted = tuple(sorted(mult.items(), reverse=True))
        item1 = [item[0] for item in mult_sorted]
        item2 = [item[1] for item in mult_sorted]
        a=a[:n]
        return loop_rec(a, n - 1, item1, item2)
    else:
       return (item1,item2)
(a,b)=loop_rec(a,len(a)-1,[0],[1])
print(a)
print(b)
```

You can compute the multiplication polynomial that vanishes on roots from a list without NumPy and it is very useful in the field of cryptography whenever we have field elements and need a list as the result and not in the class of NumPy.

```py
[out]: 
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 6, 11, 6]
```